# How to set expiration time for a link sent via Email?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I send a link as email to the users asking them to reset the password. Clicking on the link redirects to a page in my project. How can I set the expiration time for this link to 24 hours, and how do I know if this link is not re-used again? Whats the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi. You will have to show what you have tried already. Stack Overflow is a platform to receive help on physical coding issues. (Problems with code). Do some research, and update your question with more specific details.

Comment: If you want the easiest way then you can try the [online temporary link generator](https://expiry.link) websites. They have options to expire link based on clicks or time.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how your process looks like but the recommend way is to use a guid to identify the 
passwort reset process.

This is how a process should look like.

1. Create a database table with the userId, createDate, closeDate, and a guid
2. Create a new entry in the table
3. Send the mail with a link to your page that has the uuid from the entry
4. If the user enters the page (clicks the link) you check if the process is still open (closeDate is null)
5. Check if the createDate is within the last 24 hours
6. User can change password
7. You set the closeDate

Answer (score 0):

store email sent date&time in the database(where your maintaning userdetails) .
 when your are open link for reset password capture present date. compare both date&time values . they you can procced. may this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea

1. Create a Time.now() and encrypt this using encryption and attach with your link
2. Send using Email and other option
3. go to the link page
4. write code on page load Request the sent encrypted Date Time and decipher it
5. match time if time is over then send to an error page else continue

Like -:- http://Yourhost/foldername.aspx?val=encryptedTimeDate